# # function that given an array A consisting of N integers, returns the sum of all two -digit numbers.

Tags: python-2.7

## function that given an array A consisting of N integers, returns the sum of all two -digit numbers.

def solution(A):
    # write your code in Python 2.7
  sum = 0
  for i in A:
    if i in range(0,1000):
        sum = sum+i
  return sum
A = [47,1900,1,90,45]

why would i get 183 instead of 182,please assist

Running solution...
Compilation successful.

Example test:   [1, 1000, 80, -91]
WRONG ANSWER (got 81 expected -11)

Example test:   [47, 1900, 1, 90, 45]
WRONG ANSWER (got 183 expected 182)

Detected some errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in the first case you are just considering positive numbers and single digit numbers, which is in turn the problem for the second case.

test 1) 1+80=81

test 2) 47+1+90+45=183

Comment: # you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
# print "this is a debug message"

def solution(A):
    # write your code in Python 2.7
  sum = -1
  for i in A:
    if i in range(-91,1000):
        sum = sum+i
  return sum
A = [1,1000,80,-91]

Comment: It worked !# you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
# print "this is a debug message"

def solution(A):
    # write your code in Python 2.7
  sum = -1
  for i in A:
    if i in range(-91,1000):
        sum = sum+i
  return sum
A = [1,1000,80,-91]